# Caja dropbox extension doesn’t update when a file is uploaded

Tags: icons, mate, dropbox, caja

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu mate and the problem is using Caja file manager , when I change/create a new file/folder in a dropbox folder, the status of icon doesn't update (see the screenshot):

[image]

in Caja, if I press Ctrl+R, then dropbox status icons updates so the problem is the dropbox extension doesn't updates when a file is uploaded.

Do you also have the same problem? I want to know if it is a bug or a problem that can be fixed.

The version of Caja file manager is V1.12.7 
The version of Caja dropbox extension is 1.12.0

Comment: how did you install the extension? I did `sudo apt install caja-dropbox` and it works for me - version is 1.16.0-1 in MATE 16.10

Comment: tnx for comment. I reinstalled the extension and now it works!

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is not reproducible and seemingly only relevant to 1 user

Comment: seems like anybody has a fresh installation of Ubuntu Mate will face the same problem so it is not only me. Also it can help people to get ride of similar problems with the same type of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the extension and it works perfectly:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall caja-dropbox
```